# HTML2Canvas not capturing canvas data in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, svg, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I am using **HTML2Canvas** to capture screenshot of my html page and save it as image in server.
My Html contains a **d3.js** chart and html elements. d3.js chart is generated as svg, so to capture svg, I use **Fabric.js** to convert svg to canvas element. After this process is complete I use Html2Canvas to capture the entire web page as image and save it in server.

The whole process is working fine in Chrome and FF. Problem is when using IE. In IE 11, everything else in the page is captured except the chart canvas element.

Any help provided will be much appreciated.

**Screen capture Code:**

function SaveHtmlAsImage(item, idx)

{

//Create a new canvas element

```
var canvasId = 'canvas' + idx;
```

// Get the SVG which needs to be captured.

```
var svg = d3.select(item).select("svg");

var d3canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

d3canvas.id = canvasId;

d3canvas.width = svg.attr('width');

d3canvas.height = svg.attr('height');

// add the canvas to html body

document.body.appendChild(d3canvas);
```

//Convert the svg to canvas using Fabric.js

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg.node().parentNode.innerHTML, function (objects, options)
```

{

```
  var canvasObj = new fabric.Canvas(canvasId);

    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

    canvasObj.add(obj).renderAll();
```

//Replace the svg with canvas element.

```
    d3.select(item).select("svg").remove();


    $(item).find('#ChartItem').append(d3canvas);
```

//Use Html2Canvas to capture the whole html to save it as image.

```
html2canvas(item,{
        onrendered: function (canvas) {                
            var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/bmp");
            var image = canvasdata.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
            imageDataLst.push({ key: idx, imageData: image);                              
        }
    }, { width: 1250, height: 750 });

});
```

}

Please provide your suggestions to fix this issue.

Comment: IE < Edge did taint the canvas as soon as an SVG image has been drawn to it by `drawImage`. h2c does use this method to draw svg on canvas, and maybe fabricjs too.  The only way to circumvent this is to use the canvasAPI drawing methods to redraw your svg on the canvas. Some libraries, like canvg does it for you.

Comment: @Kaiido : Thanks for the quick reply. I tried canvg.js before going to Fabric.js but my svg is a complex one[Radar chart/bubble chart]. the svg to canvas conversion throws error when using canvg.js. Below is the error which I get if I use canvg.

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext' File: canvg.js

Comment: This error means that you didn't provided a canvas element as parameter of `canvg(canvasElement, svgString)`

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for pointing the root cause for the error. Now the error is gone and canvg converts the svg to canvas but with some issues. The chart contains some svg images inside its svg element. Those svg images are not retaining their dimensions correctly and hence those images are overlapping the entire chart. [Note: I have set the height and width for the svg icons inside the chart but during conversion the icons loose their height and width.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause for this issue to be another svg icon which was embedded inside the chart. Replacing the svg icon with png image fixed this issue.

Sorry for the inconvenience.
Hope it helps someone in future.