# Why is canvas2image not capturing a plotly.js chart in a screenshot?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, plotly

I am using html2canvas and canvas2image to take screen shots of math quizzes that I have made with rails 5. It works great except for quiz problems that use Plotly.js charts. The html text of the quiz problem is captured but not the dynamic plotly chart that accompanies the problem.  I thought the screen shot would capture everything that is visible on the page. Any help would be great!!!

Comment: are using Plotly.toImage method to get the image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665790/html2canvas-not-capturing-canvas-data-in-ie11/42763676 check this link this might help